# Angular 2 component using plain/vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

Due to some architectural decisions, my team has decided to fallback to using Javascript without any framework dependencies (Angular or react).

I would now want to write custom components(that do the exact same thing as Angular's components: a selector that can be used in HTML with a scope & a controller to play with) with no dependencies on frameworks.

jQuery widgets is an option we thought of. But there's a dependency on jQuery :(

What's the best approach to proceed? 
Does ES6 provide any ways to do this?

Comment: Do you imagine how angular component works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is parsing the html and searching to match with the selectors.. before this, it parses your templates to generate dynamic code... and a lot more things under the hood.. so, no, you wont be able to create a custom html tag easily. 
Maybe take a look at Polymer? 
https://www.polymer-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Why bother creating something what is sucessfully done by a huge team of developers on your own? You will most likely fail.

But if you still want to try it, there's a thing called [**WebComponents**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), but it has very limited browser support at the moment. A better support would also lead to another library called [**Polymer**](https://www.polymer-project.org/).

Another lightweight library to create custom components is [**Vue.js**](https://vuejs.org/).

Fyi: [**React**](https://reactjs.org/) isn't a framework.

Comment: Right. You have a definitely valid argument. But we have apps built over various libraries namely Angularjs, Angular, React & some are still with jQuery widgets. Say an instance - we write these components with Angular, apps written in angularjs or just jQuery may not be able to import it. Is there a way where I can create components using angular, and transpile it to plain JS & import it to any project